# How to nest an array of hashes with group by as json?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I have data that looks like this:

```
[
  {date: '2014/10/01', group: 'a', node: '2'},
  {date: '2014/10/01', group: 'b', node: '3'},
  {date: '2014/10/02', group: 'a', node: '4'},
  {date: '2014/10/02', group: 'b', node: '1'}
]
```

How would I go about first grouping by date like so:

```
.group_by{|x| [x.date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")}
```

but then by `group` and then `node` and render that as a nested json?

I'm looking for something like this:

```
[
  {'2014/10/01': {groups: [{a: ['2'], b: ['3']}]},
  {'2014/10/02': {groups: [{a: ['4'], b: ['1']}]},
]
```

Comment: Please post the expected resulting JSON.

Comment: The first element of your desired output is: `{:"2014/10/01"=>{:groups=>[{:a=>["2"], :b=>["3"]}]}}`. Was it your intention to convert the date string to a symbol? If not, replace `:` with `=>`. Also, why do you want the value of `groups` to be an array containing a single hash, rather than just the hash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
arr = [
  {date: '2014/10/01', group: 'a', node: '2'},
  {date: '2014/10/01', group: 'b', node: '3'},
  {date: '2014/10/02', group: 'a', node: '4'},
  {date: '2014/10/02', group: 'b', node: '1'}
]

arr.group_by { |item| item[:date] }.map do |k,v|
  Hash[k, { groups: v.map { |g| Hash[g[:group], [g[:node]]] }}]
end
#  => [{"2014/10/01"=>{:groups=>[{"a"=>["2"]}, {"b"=>["3"]}]}}, {"2014/10/02"=>{:groups=>[{"a"=>["4"]}, {"b"=>["1"]}]}}]
```

Comment: OP requested the groups to be stored as arrays: `Hash[g[:group], [*g[:node]]]`.

Comment: Joseph said he wants `[{a: ['2'], b: ['3']}]` (i.e., an array containing a single element, a hash), not an array of hashes.   He also ask that the date be converted to a symbol. Changing your answer to meet those requirements would not be difficult, but I don't think you should do so. Considering that he gave you the greenie, it appears that your answer better reflects what he wants rather than what he said he wants.

Answer (score 1):

When faced with problems like this one, involving multiple transformations to the data, I often find it useful to divide the problem into two steps, the first being to create an array or hash that contains all the essential information; the second being to format that data in the form desired.

It's best to describe the procedure around an example. The one given in the question is fine:

```
arr = [
  {date: '2014/10/01', group: 'a', node: '2'},
  {date: '2014/10/01', group: 'b', node: '3'},
  {date: '2014/10/02', group: 'a', node: '4'},
  {date: '2014/10/02', group: 'b', node: '1'}
]
```

As we will be grouping on the date, it makes sense to extract the data from `arr` into a hash whose keys are dates. The values of those keys are hashes that contain key-value pairs corresponding to the values of `:group` and `:node` in each element of `arr`. I've chosen to do that using the form of [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) that uses a block to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged:

```
h = arr.each_with_object({}) { |g,h|
  h.update(g[:date]=>{ g[:group]=>g[:node] }) { |_,oh,nh|oh.update(nh) } }
  #=> {"2014/10/01"=>{"a"=>"2", "b"=>"3"},
  #    "2014/10/02"=>{"a"=>"4", "b"=>"1"}}
```

Before moving on to the formatting step, I should point out that, depending on requirements, it may more convenient to use this hash in subsequent calculations, rather than the array requested.

Formatting is now straightforward, using [Enumerable#map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map):

```
h.map { |d,g| { d=>{groups: [g] } } }
  #=> [{"2014/10/01"=>{:groups=>[{"a"=>"2", "b"=>"3"}]}},
  #    {"2014/10/02"=>{:groups=>[{"a"=>"4", "b"=>"1"}]}}]
```